# IOS высота cell в зависимости от текста

Tags: ios7, ios, coredata, tableview

Я получаю обьект из CoreData следующим образом:

```
self.name = [[abc anyObject] valueForKey:@"name"]
```

и отображаю его:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name];
cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Помещается текст не полностью. Как менять высоту cell в зависимости от текста?

Comment: @daves, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(286.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    UIFont *theFont  = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    CGSize theSize;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        CGRect frame = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:theFont} context:nil];
    theSize = frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        theSize = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }

    return theSize.height;
    }
```

Обновлено для iOS 7 и выше.

Comment: @AlessandroDP а зачем здесь нужен mArray?

Comment: Ну это простой пример, в котором из массива берутся данные

Comment: а если у меня нет массива и мне нужно всего лишь использовать текст из self.name

Comment: Ну так запихни в массив, в чем проблема? +Откуда у тебя берется кол-во ячеек?

Comment: кол-во ячеек всего 1, поэтому и не хочу в массив пихать

Comment: [self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] - неужели так трудно это заменить на ваш self.name??? Что еще здесь может быть непонятно?))

Comment: Хотелось бы отметить что в данном случае не обьязательно использование массива, я подставлял просто строку. Так же, если на строке есть еще несколько Label помимо нужного нам- в CGSizeMake(286.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX); вместо 286.0f надо подставлять значения меньше. Так же в - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath я прописывал для label.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @daves, ну это же очевидно и я вам сказал, что это пример. Также сказал, чтобы вы подставили вместо элемента массива свое значение. 286.0f - это опять таки очевидно - это просто мое значение в примере, я же не в курсе ваших. Кол-во строк в лейбле - опять таки очевидно.)) 

В общем и целом хорошо, если вам это помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Наилучший общий способ, который я пока придумал, такой.

1. Выносите весь контент (view'шки) из cell'а в отдельную view (можно её назвать как-то вроде `BlaBlaCellContentView`).
2. В этой view заводите класс-метод, который вам возвратит высоту ячейки с определенными данными (типа `+ (CGFloat) heightForData:(Data *)data maxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth`).
3. В этом методе для вычисления высоты, просто делаете layout всех ваших вьюшек (как обычно делаете в layoutSubviews) и выставляете фрейм для самой вьюшки.
4. Далее, в cell'е заводите weak синглтон (хотя необязательно weak, можно обычный синглтон) для этой вьюшки и делаете аналогичный метод для вычисления высоты, примерно такой:

   ```
   - (void) sizeToFitWithWidth:(CGFloat)width
   {
       self.Width = width;
       [self layout];
       self.Height = self.bottomLabel.BottomY + kMarginY;
   }

   + (CGFloat) heightForProduct:(IHerbProduct *)product width:(CGFloat)width
   {
       CartItemCellContentView *sharedCellContentView = [self sharedWeakInstance];
       sharedCellContentView.product = product;
       [sharedCellContentView sizeToFitWithWidth:width];
       CGFloat height = sharedCellContentView.Height;
       return height;
   }
   ```

   (замечу, что .Width, .Height, BottomY - это из моей собственной категории для UIView, но из названий и так понятно, что они возвращают).

Ну и код для weak синглтона (смысл - живет до тех пор, пока на него есть хотя бы одна ссылка. Если уничтожился, то при следующем вызове создастся заново):

```
+ (instancetype) sharedWeakInstance
{
    static __weak id weakInstance = nil;
    id strongInstance = weakInstance;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!strongInstance) {
            strongInstance = [self new];
            weakInstance = strongInstance;
        }
    }

    return strongInstance;
}
```

P.S. Пришёл к таком подходу, т.к.:

1. `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` не всегда даёт те же результаты, что и `[UILabel sizeToFit]`.
2. Для сложных cell'ов приходится писать слишком много сложного кода для вычисления высоты - оказалось проще переиспользовать код для layout'а.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас будет много ячеек разной высота, то можно вынести подсчет высоты в отдельный метод.

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: (CGFloat)width {
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

И потом уже получать высоту:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16.0];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrsDictionary];    
CGFloat height = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:attrString andWidth:280];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0f;
}
```

Всё! :)