# Деление переменной на массивы в tableview

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день, перечитал много документации, но так и не нашел фреймворка который позволяет создавать контроллер с диалоговыми окнами (или даже не знаю как их назвать), он используется в сообщениях, в WhatsApp, Viber, VK, короче везде где есть переписка. Как он называется и где его искать?

Теперь перейду к **самому вопросу**, допустим я получаю такую переменную с сервера:

> id = 15176809, received = 05.06.2014
> 10:40:24, phone = 71234567890, message
> = Как дела?, to_phone = 799999999999, sent = 05.06.2014
> 10:40:24
>
> id = 15176810, received = 05.06.2014
> 10:41:24, phone = 71234567890, message
> = Что молчишь?, to_phone = 7999999999, sent = 05.06.2014 10:41:24

И мне ее нужно как-то грамотно утрамбовать в UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle (TableView, потому что не знаю как сделать мессенджер).

message я засуну в основной текст, а phone и received засуну в subtitle через /n.

**Как правильно будет сделать? Подскажите алгоритм действий.**

У меня мозг просто закипел пока я думал над алгоритмом, но собирался я делить через  `componentsSeparatedByString:@","`.
Но все мои мысли заходили в тупик.

Comment: Кто сервер писал? На кол его посадить, и не давать вставать пока все на JSON не переведет!!!!
А по существу я бы ответил на этот вопрос (хотя наститываю их уже 3), но надо блог завести, а то текста много будет. Скачайте книгу, почитайте документацию. А там уже и вопросы можно будет формулировать правильные. IMHO. И еще, советую, мозг всегда будет кипеть, и хоть ни всегда зря, но прочтение документации в разы ускоряет понимание!!!

Comment: Сервер писал оператор, работает он на API (Я ничего сделать там не могу, т.к. я обычный клиент, и под меня они подгибаться не будут). В документации нету ничего о мессенджерах, а вот на счет TableView и массива я прочитал достаточно много, но ответа так и не нашел, не могли бы вы просто словесно составить цепочку действий?

Comment: Извиняюсь, всё таки можно поменять параметр получения, итог такой:
[{
"id": 15176809,
"received": "05.06.2014 10:40:24",
"phone": "791234567890",
"message": "Как дела?",
"to_phone": "79999999999",
"sent": "05.06.2014 10:40:24"
}]

Comment: Ну в принципе всё, дальше я уже сам, спасибо за ответ, иначе я б так и мудохался с строкой.

Для тех кто попал сюда с гугла, переходите на JSON, ну а урок по работе с JSON'ом на xCode можете смотреть тут:
http://www.imaladec.com/story/json

Answer (score 1):

1. По UI: в таких случаях проще унаследоваться от `UITableViewCell`, накидать туда своих вьюшек (`UILabel`-ов и т.д.), и самому их заполнять и лэйаутить (в `layoutSubviews`). Переменную высоту ячеек можно сделать например по моему [методу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/323857/ios7-ios-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-cell-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=325020#325020).
2. По парсингу: эсли это приходит CSV с сервера, то можно заюзать какую-нибудь либу для CSV, например [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) (для поиска либ пользуйтесь `pod search`).